# Apple RAM for MacBook Pro vs other brands

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, unibody

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apple-Certified RAM?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/apple-certified-ram)

Apple RAM for the unibody MacBook Pro's typically has a large markup to it. I am wondering if it's different than Crucial or other brands in quality..

Answer (score 2):

I have also used Crucial memory in my MacBook Pros and have never had an issue with it.

Apple's [support doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1270#link3) gives the memory specs to match against and does not require "Apple" RAM.

Answer (score 1):

No different from a brand like Crucial. In fact I have had the experience in the past of adding Crucial RAM to a Mac system and the system profiler reporting the exact same manufacturer code and part number for the new module as the already existing ones