# Anyone have any experience installing Corsair CM3X4GSD1066 memory on a Macbook Pro mid 2009?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, unibody

Is the memory compatible for use in the mid-2009 aluminum unibody MBP?

Reference: http://www.corsair.com/products/valueselect/default.aspx#notebook

The specification is compatible, but from my research, there are at least two conflicting user reviews on this matter:

- Amazon product page, which said that it is compatible, but failed after five months.
- newegg product page which says that it is not compatible, however it does not specify the MBP in detail.

Sorry I can't provide links for newegg & amazon page, don't have enough rep.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably too late (should have posted this at the time), but see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/macbook-pro-memory for more general tips on memory compatibility.